# Why is my canvas not completely in front?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I Dont know why my canvas isnt showing up in front complety even though i have set the sort order to five, which is the highest. AS you see, the text is behind an item, but the item is in another canvas, which has a lower Sort Order.

[image]

Comment: check the z values of all the elements

Comment: i checked them, they all have 0.

Comment: Show us the other canvas and hierarchy